# In Python's Seaborn, is there any way to do the opposite of `despine`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

`seaborn` is a beautiful Python package that acts, for the most part, as an additional layer on top of `matplotlib`.  However, it changes, for instance, things that would be `matplotlib` methods on a plot object to direct `seaborn` functions.

---

`seaborn`'s `despine()` **remove** any spines (the outer edges of the plot) from a plot.  But I cannot do the opposite.

I cannot seem to recreate the spine in the standard way that I would / could if I had used `matplotlib` entirely from the start.  Is there a way to do that?  How would I?

---

Below is an example.  Could I, for instance, add a spine on the bottom and the left of the plot?

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd

tmp = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(tmp.data, columns=tmp.feature_names)
iris['species'] = tmp.target_names[tmp.target]
iris.species =  iris.species.astype('category') 

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.boxplot(x='species', y='sepal length (cm)', data=iris_new)
plt.show()
```

[image: associated boxplot]

Comment: The `darkgrid` style has no spines by default. You need to pick another style -- matplotlib has many of its own now. You can also import seaborn without any affects on the style by doing `import seaborn.apionly as sns`

Comment: Paul is correct, although the full answer is a little bit more subtle. `despine` actually removes the spine objects, whereas the `darkgrid` style sets the `axes.linewidth` (aka the spines) to 0. You can specify additional rc params on top of the default `darkgrid`, or choose a different style.

Comment: @mwaskom thanks for clarifying. very good to know.

Comment: Actually I guess my comment isn't totally correct. `despine` doesn't remove the spine objects, it toggles their `visibility` parameter. It's still a different mechanism from what the default style is doing, though.

Comment: @PaulH I know that `darkgrid` has no spines by default.  But it also has several other settings that I **do** like.  I don't want to throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all the great comments!  I knew some of what you wrote, but not that ***both*** the `'axes.linewidth'` ***and*** `'axes.edgecolor'` needed to be set.

I'm writing an answer here, since it is a compilation of a few comments.

---

That is, the following code generates the plot below:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid', {'axes.linewidth': 2, 'axes.edgecolor':'black'})
sns.boxplot(x='species', y='sepal length (cm)', data=iris_new)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: BTW things will look a little nicer if you use a dark gray (i.e., `".15"`) rather than `"black"`. This is both true [in general](http://ianstormtaylor.com/design-tip-never-use-black/) and specifically because that is the color of the other seaborn plot elements.

Comment: Thanks, @mwaskom!  I agree.  However, for my example, I wanted to make the code as simple as possible, not introducing concepts outside of my main question.