# Move Colorbar closer to Heatmap (Seaborn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

My colorbar is very far away from the bottom of my heatmap. Is there a way to move it closer?

My code is:

```
import seaborn as sns

Granger2 = Granger
Granger2.columns = Granger_colnames
Granger2.index = Granger_rownames

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,25)) 
sns.heatmap(Granger2, cmap=rvb, cbar=True, ax=ax,linewidths=.5,cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"})
ax.xaxis.tick_top() # x axis on top
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

#Remove ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)

# Drawing the frame
ax.axhline(y = 0, color='k',linewidth = 1)
ax.axhline(y = Granger2.shape[0], color = 'k',linewidth = 1)  
ax.axvline(x = 0, color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
ax.axvline(x = Granger2.shape[1], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See also [In Python's Seaborn, is there any way to do the opposite of `despine`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318110/in-pythons-seaborn-is-there-any-way-to-do-the-opposite-of-despine) to show the "frame".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use e.g. `cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "pad":0.02}`. The padding is a fraction of the subplot height, so 0.02 is 2%. See the [colorbar docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) for more information about `pad` and other parameters.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights = flights.pivot('year', 'month').droplevel(0, axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 20))
sns.heatmap(flights, cmap='Greens', cbar=True, ax=ax, linewidths=.5,
            cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal", "pad": 0.02})
ax.xaxis.tick_top()  # x axis on top
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

# Remove ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)

# Drawing the frame
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('0.15')
ax.patch.set_linewidth(2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: changing the colorbar padding for sns.heatmap]